# How do I start an Intent inside a Compose function's button click

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to redirect the user to another activity that opens a internet url. On button click.

Here is my code so far

```
Button(onClick = {
          val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
          // Here is some code that starts the activity
       }) {
          Text(text="APPLY HACK")
       }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
    startActivity(context, intent, null) }
) {
    Text("BUTTON")
}
```

Comment: This answer is not ful.  It workds only when you are in activity. Not in separate composable function

Answer (score 4):

```
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"))) }
) {
    Text("Click here")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
    val webIntent: Intent = Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com/users/18910957/oolyvi?tab=profile").let { webPage -> 
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webPage)
}
try {
    startActivity(context, webIntent, null)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        // Define what your app should do if no activity can handle the intent.
}
) {
    Text("APPLY HACK")
}
```

You can do it something like this, just parse link address to the Uri and then call the intent for an action

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).