# How open external app from Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want open an external app such as mailer app (with "to" and "subject" by default) from a jetpack compose button or image button. In layout xml I know, but with this new Jetpack Compose I don't. Help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start an Intent inside a Compose function's button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940091/how-do-i-start-an-intent-inside-a-compose-functions-button-click)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO)
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")) // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses)
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
    val context = LocalContext.current    
    Button(onClick = {
    startActivity(context, intent, null) }
    ) {
        Text("BUTTON")
    }
```