# Can I use Compose and Standard Activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I found a good tutorial how to make a calendar with Jetpack Compose, for that I created a Compose Empty Activity to implement it.

Since it's for school I can't use only compose to develop my app, my question is if I can have some activites made with compose and others with normal kotlin code and xml?

I was testing it and it keeps crashing when I use an Intent to go from a compose activity to a standard one.

Is there a way to use the two methods?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is if I can have some activites made with compose and others with normal kotlin code and xml?

Yes!

> I was testing it and it keeps crashing when I use an Intent to go from a compose activity to a standard one.

You might want to ask a separate question, where you provide the stack trace of your crash and the code that is causing the crash. Make sure that all of your activities have `<activity>` elements in your manifest! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66940172/115145) for a demonstration of launching a third-party activity; to launch one of your own, construct the proper `Intent` for it.